# Access Query DSN-less connection string error

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, database-connection, pass-through

I have a query that when created, used an ODBC to connect to an SQL Database.
I now need to change that because the Access file will be shared and used across our company, and I don't want to have to put ODBCs on all those computers separately if I can help it.

So, some quick google searching later I went into the query and found the property 'ODBC Connect Str' and updated it to (hopefully) connect independent of the ODBC.

The old connection string (which worked fine) was:

```
ODBC; DSN=Orderwise 2;Description=Orderwise Connection;UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword;DATABASE=LIVEDATA
```

The new connection string is currently:

```
ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Dc01/Orderwise;Database=LIVEDATA;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypassword;
```

but whenever I try to save or run the query, it gives me the error that

> ODBC -- connection to `{SQL Server}Dc01/Orderwise' failed.

I've tried it without the `ODBC;` section on the new string and it didn't work either. Subsequent google searches on the error aren't getting me any further.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong please?

Comment: Assuming `Orderwise` is an instance name, use a backslash instead of forward slash to separate the server and instance name components: `Server=Dc01/Orderwise` to `Server=Dc01\Orderwise`.

Comment: @DanGuzman it works, Thank you so much!! would you like to convert that to an answer rather than a comment so I can accept it properly?

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense, but it works for me.

```
Driver={SQL Server};ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=Dc01/Orderwise;Database=LIVEDATA;Uid=myusername;Pwd=mypassword;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).